# caching a collection of users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have list of users i would like to cache for a certain amount of time but I have trouble with making connection to my model in getting users.

In my service layer:

```
public IEnumerable<Clients> GetClientVw(int sessionID)
            {
                var _key = GetVwCacheKey(sessionID);
                if (_cacheManager.Exists(_key, _cacheSettings.Group))
                {
                    return _cacheManager.Get<Clients>(_key, _cacheSettings.AbsoluteExpiration.AddHours(1.0).ToString());
                }
                var _result = GetClients(sessionID);
                if (_result != null)
                {
                    var _clientVw = _result.ClientsVw();
                    _cacheManager.Set<ClientsVw>(_key, _clientVw, _cacheSettings);
                    return _clientVw;
                }

                return null;
            }
```

This is what i have in my Model:

```
public class ClientsVw
    {
        public ClientsVw()
        {
            this.Clients = new HashSet<Clients>();
        }
        public IEnumerable<Clients> ClientsList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clients
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

**Errors:** in my `return _cacheManager.Get<Clients>` it is telling me i am missing a cast because i cannot convert from Clients to IEnumerable

And in `var _clientVw = _result.ClientVw();`it says that i don't have a definition for ClientVw()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOR it is telling me i am missing a cast because i cannot convert from Clients to IEnumerable

you can try making it to list

```
  return _cacheManager.Get<Clients>(_key, _cacheSettings.AbsoluteExpiration.AddHours(1.0).ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: the to list is not being seen as a possibility only shows ToString()